# MSHP file from SAGA tough to delete

Tags: qgis, shapefile, pyqgis, saga, qgis-processing

After running a SAGA line dissolve process in QGIS, an MSHP file is created (amongst other things). Fine by me, though I'm not sure what it's used for (metadata in XML format?). Problem is that it can't be deleted without closing QGIS. This is a problem, as I'm running the process repeatedly in a Python script.

Here is the relevant code:

```
lines_layer = some_vector_polygon_layer
dissolved_lines_path = "SOME SHAPEFILE PATH HERE"
unused_field = lines_layer.dataProvider().fields()[0].name() # Name of a field, not used
processing.runalg("saga:linedissolve", lines_layer, unused_field, unused_field, unused_field, 1, dissolved_lines_path)
```

I then load the resulting layer and add it to the map registry & table of contents. Shortly after, I delete the layer from the map registry (& table of contents).

I can delete the resulting SHP quite fine, but I am unable to delete the MSHP. There are no errors in the resulting shapefile or in the processing log. Any ideas?